# Why Can't insert another field and edit the field in Strapi CMS?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

[image]

Hello, I would like to add another fields and edit some fields, but not able to do them.
Could you let me know what is the problem? Thanks

Comment: It seems this is a production live right?

Comment: Yes, correct. It is a live site.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can only insert or update in local environment.